# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IS_EQUAL, expecting

Tags: php, syntax, isset

I'm getting the following error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_IS_EQUAL, expecting ','
or ')' in C:\etc\display.php on line 115
```

Line 115 of display.php:

`if ((!isset($_POST['login']==NULL) OR !isset($_POST['passwd']==NULL)))
msgerror("<font size=4>Fill all the missing fields and try again.</font>");`

I'm sure it's a syntax problem on using ISSET, but I just can't get rid of this error and make it work (sorry for being such a newbie).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be

```
if ( !isset($_POST['login']) || !isset($_POST['passwd']) ) { 
    msgerror("Fill all the missing fields and try again."); 
}
```

more info on `isset`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

logical operators: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `==NULL`s, they're completely unnecessary and I'm not sure I can work out why you put them there in the first place...

Also, it is preferable to use `||` instead of `or`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if (!isset($_POST['login']) || empty($_POST['login']) || !isset($_POST['passwd']) || empty($_POST['passwd']))
msgerror("<font size=4>Fill all the missing fields and try again.</font>");
```

Comment: the `<font>` tag is deprecated; you should use CSS for styling